# angular 2 Unhandled promise rejection TypeError

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm new to angular and typescript. I'm getting error "Unhandled promise rejection TypeError: Cannot set property"

here is my code:

login.component.ts

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private loginService: LoginService) { }


submitError = false; // set "true" to show error 

onSubmit(){

  this.submitError = false;
  this.submitErrorText = "";    
  this.model = this.loginForm.value;
  this.loginService.authenticate(this.model.login_id, this.model.password)
  .then(res => {

    if(res.status == 404){

      this.submitError = true; 

    }
    else{
      // do something
    }

  }).catch(function(err: any){

    this.submitError = true; // Unhandled promise rejection TypeError: Cannot set property 'submitError' of undefined



  });




}
```

login-service.ts

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

@Injectable()
export class LoginService{


private auth_url = "/login/api/auth";

constructor(private http: Http){};

authenticate(username: String, pass: String): Promise<any>{
    return this.http.post(this.auth_url, {username: username,pass: pass})
                        .toPromise()
                        .then(response => response.json())
                        .catch(this.handleError);
}

private handleError(error: any): Promise<any>{

    return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
}

}
```

submitError is class level property, why its not accessible or undefined.
what is the proper way to access it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're facing a common problem in JavaScript.

Fortunately, in ES6 and TypeScript you can use an arrow function (lambda expression) to lexically capture the meaning of `this`.

```
}).catch((err:any) => {
    this.submitError = true; // this works
});

}).catch(function (err:any) {
        this.submitError = true; // this doesn't work
});
```

More information about arrow functions: [Arrow Functions](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/arrow-functions.html)

Comment: @Jawad you're welcome, I'm glad I've managed to help you. I saw that you had accepted my answer, but could you please vote up too (click on the up arrow above the number (which is now 0) on the left side of the answer)?

Answer (score 1):

Change it to:

```
.catch(
  (err:any) => 
  {
    this.submitError = true;
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The good approach to use `httpService` is when you call the `httpService` and return the `json` data, then you need to handle this data as it is `response` or `error`.. You need to `subscribe` the data.

In `login.component.ts`

```
this.loginService.authenticate(this.model.login_id, this.model.password)
 .subscribe((response) => {

    if(response.status == 404){

      this.submitError = true; 

    }
    else{
      // do something
    }

  },
    error => {
           console.log(error);
           this.submitError = true;  
   });
```