# Typescript Circular dependency detected when services calling each other

Tags: angular, typescript

I have 2 service components:
PromiseService.service.ts (handling defer calls and async calls)

```
@Injectable()
export class PromiseService{
    constructor(private staffservice: StaffService) {}
    defercall(asyncCalls, syncCalls) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const promises = asyncCalls.map(function(val){return val();});
        Promise.all(promises).then(result => {
            resolve(result); });
        });
    }
}
```

and StaffService.service.ts (handling staff info)

```
@Injectable()
export class StaffService{
    constructor(private promises: PromiseService) {}
    updateStaffInfo(){
        this.promises.defercall(this.updateid, this.updateaddress);
    }
    updateid() {
    }
}
```

However, I got the following errors:

*Circular dependency detected:
StaffService.service.ts->PromiseService.service.ts->StaffService.service.ts*

I tried to change the Promise Service component and take away the following lines:

However, another error comes out:
*Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot read property 'updateid' of undefined ; Zone:  ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: Cannot read property 'updateid' of undefined*

How to make the PromiseService recognise that "this" is referring to the StaffService?
I got stuck by this error for 1 week already. Thank you!

UPDATE:
Thank you for the replies. I have removed the StaffService declaration in PromiseService and the updated StaffService typescript is:

```
@Injectable()
export class StaffService{
    staffid: any;
    staffaddress: any;
    constructor(private promises: PromiseService){}
    updateid(id) {
        this.staffid = id;
    }
    updateStaffInfo() {
        promises.defercall(this.updateid, this.updateaddress);
    }
    updateaddress(address) {
        this.staffaddress = address;
    }
}
```

but when I run the application (ng serve), the following error comes out:

*Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot read property 'updateid' of undefined ; Zone: ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: Cannot read property 'updateid' of undefined*

*Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot read property 'updateaddress' of undefined ; Zone: ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: Cannot read property 'updateaddress' of undefined*

Thank you so much.

Comment: remove StaffService from PromiseService.

Comment: thank you @Subhan, warning disappear but error comes out: `Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot read property 'updateid' of undefined ; Zone: ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: Cannot read property 'updateid' of undefined`

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve. What do you want to do with the updadeid?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
constructor(private staffservice: StaffService) {}
```

To

```
constructor() {}
```

Your promise service doesn't need a dependency to a business service.

Comment: My wrong to not mentioned in the question, I tried to remove the private declaration in Promise service. Yes, the circular dependency warning disappear but the `this.updateid` can never be referenced. Error comes out: `Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot read property 'updateid' of undefined ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: Cannot read property 'updateid' of undefined` Thank you.

Comment: This is another issue, not related to your promise service. It is saying it can't find the `updateid` property. If you posted your whole code, I could tell you why.

Comment: I have updated the post with the detail information in the staffservice typescript, thank you!

Comment: The error should tell you which line of your project is in error. Could you post the trace of your error ? (as text, not as an image)

Comment: Hi @trichetriche, I know why my code is not working, it is because the `this` cannot be interpreted in PromiseService, workaround found in another post in stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40100775/angular-2-unhandled-promise-rejection-typeerror , thank you so much anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Your code something wrong, what is this `this.updateid`? if your refer like this it is called variable but you are not decalred any variable.

Then only error shown like this.`Cannot read property 'updateid' of undefined`.

You have to refer method use like this. `this.updateid()` make sure that method return some value.If not return value it will still occur undefined error. Also your method not implemented.

Your `PromiseService` service file no need to declare like this. please remove.

```
constructor(private staffservice: StaffService) {}
```

please solve this are the things and run and let me know once.

Comment: I parse in `this.updateid` so that PromiseService can use it for asyncCall, but it turns out that PromiseService cannot refer `this` to StaffService. Thank you.